# Assertion error: assert n_dims + n_parameters + n_funs == n_args

Tags: python, differential-equations

I was solving the differential equation with two variables. I am using pydens library. But I think I am doing something wrong while defining the parameters and getting assertion error. Can anyone help to point out where I am going wrong? I am using tensor flow v1.14, and python v3.6. Am I defining the lambda function correctly?

```
import os
import sys
import math
import pandas as pd
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from tensorflow import logging
logging.set_verbosity(logging.ERROR)
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tqdm import tqdm_notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
sys.path.append('..')
from pydens import Solver, NumpySampler, cart_prod, add_tokens
from pydens import plot_loss, plot_pair_1d, plot_2d, plot_sections_2d, 
plot_sections_3d
add_tokens()

pde = {
    'n_dims': 2,
    'form': lambda u, x, y, a,b,v,n: D(D(u, x), x) + D(D(u, y), y) - 
P(a)*P(b)*[exp(u/P(v)) - exp((0.0 - 1.0)*(u/P(v))) - {(exp(18.0) - 
P(n))/P(b)}],
    'boundary_condition': 1          
}                       
config = {
    'pde': pde,
    'track': {'d2x+d2y': lambda u, x, y,a,b,v, n: D(D(u, x), x) + D(D(u, y), y)},
    'train_steps': {
    'network': {'scope': '-addendums'},
    'adds': {'scope': 'addendums'},
    'ac': {'scope': '-addendums', 
           'loss':{'name': 'mse', 'predictions':'expr'}},
},
'optimizer': 'RMSProp',
}    
s = NumpySampler('u', dim=2) & NumpySampler('u', dim=1) & NumpySampler('u', dim=1)
s1 = NumpySampler('u', low=0.0, high=1.0) 
s2 = NumpySampler('u', low=5.0*exp(15.0), high=exp(16.0))
dg = Solver(config)
iters = [10, 5, 5] * 5

for _ in tqdm_notebook(range(500)):
    _ = dg.fit(batch_size=100, sampler=s, n_iters=iters[0], fetches='loss_network', train_mode='network')

    _ = dg.fit(batch_size=100, sampler=s1, n_iters=iters[1], fetches='loss_ac', train_mode='ac')

    _ = dg.fit(batch_size=100, sampler=s2, n_iters=iters[2], fetches='loss_adds', train_mode='adds')

plot_loss(dg.loss_network, color='cornflowerblue')
plot_2d(dg, fetches='solution', mode='3d_view')
plot_2d(dg, fetches='d2x+d2y', mode='contourf')
```

## AssertionError

This traceback error I am getting after running the code.

```
 File "<ipython-input-154-69cdec315cc6>", line 1, in <module>
 runfile('C:/Users/CPC/simple pde.py', wdir='C:/Users/CPC')

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
execfile(filename, namespace)

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

 File "C:/Users/CPC/simple pde.py", line 58, in <module>
dg = Solver(config)

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\pydens\wrapper.py", line 21, in _init_
self.model = model_class(config)

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\pydens\batchflow\batchflow\models\tf\base.py", line 262, in _init_
super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\pydens\batchflow\batchflow\models\base.py", line 38, in _init_
self.build(*args, **kwargs)

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\pydens\batchflow\batchflow\models\tf\base.py", line 331, in build
config = self.build_config()

 File "C:\Users\anaconda3\envs\tf-lesss\lib\site-packages\pydens\model_tf.py", line 128, in build_config
assert n_dims + n_parameters + n_funs == n_args

AssertionError

assert n_dims + n_parameters + n_funs == n_args
```

Comment: Your code is not indented properly and your error needs a traceback. Please read [ask] and [mcve] for context.